# Why does this loop run in one position but not another?

Tags: javascript

```
import { log, logTitle } from "logger";

var persons = [
  {name: "Alex", age:22},
  {name: "Maria", age:30}
]

var number = 0;

for (var i = 0; i <= persons.length; i++) {
  log(persons[i].name);
  log(persons[i].age);
  log("----------------");
  log(number)
};

while(number < 5) {
  log(number);
  number += 1;
};
```

The for loop runs and logs to screen, but none of the log statements in the while loop show up. However when I just move the while loop first, they both run. This code works:

```
while(number < 5) {
  log(number);
  number += 1;
};
for (var i = 0; i <= persons.length; i++) {
  log(persons[i].name);
  log(persons[i].age);
  log("----------------");
  log(number)
};
```

Also, if I comment out the for loop, the while loop log statements show up.

Lastly, this is the code from the imported logger file:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
export const log = content => $('#content').append("<i style = 'color: black' class = 'fa fa-terminal'> </i>  " + content + "<br>" );
export const logTitle = title => $('#title').append(title);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `persons.length` is equal to 2, but no index in `persons` array, so  should be `for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++)` not `for (var i = 0; i <= persons.length; i++)`

```js
var persons = [
  {name: "Alex", age:22},
  {name: "Maria", age:30}
]

var number = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
  console.log(persons[i].name);
  console.log(persons[i].age);
  console.log("----------------");
  console.log(number)
};

while(number < 5) {
  console.log(number);
  number += 1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the first loop contains an error in the loop condition. Change `i <= persons.length` to `i < persons.length` and it will work.

The loop throws an error when evaluating `persons[2].name`.